# WordPress Environment: Dynamic Page using shortcode - how to change the page name for sharing

Tags: php, plugin-development

I am creating a dynamic page, in a WordPress environment.  The page is created by a default standard WordPress page and then using shortcode.  Combined with URL parameters in order to retrieve the necessary data.

The problem is, this page, including the URL parameters, is "shareable" to facebook and other social media.  Thus the description that comes up is too generic.  I assume this is because the default page, on which the shortcode resides, is also generic.  That is what I want to change based on the data I am retrieving for display.

I have tried the code below and a few other variations, with no luck. In fact the filter is not even executed. Tried embedding the filter into an add_action call..the action call is done, but the filter remains executed.

```
 add_filter('wp_title','ChangeTitle', 10, 2);   
 function ChangeTitle($title, $id)
    {
    if ( $title== 'Details' ) 
       {
       $BusinessName = $_GET['Name'];   
       return $BusinessName;
       }
 return $title; 
 }
```

Does anyone have a clever way to do this?  part two of the question, would be how to assign a logo to the share.... but one thing at a time.

Comment: What your shortcode looks like? Do you need to change the title or the description?

Comment: Simple shortcut that just calls a function with just the default parameters.  I need to change the title and the description, but I can live with just the title.

[LISTING_DETAILS]

Comment: The title and the description will be based on the data I am retrieving from the database. It is not fixed. In essence, it could be hundreds of different pages, since it is dynamically created.

Comment: Where are you putting this code? If it's never getting called, then it might be in the wrong place.  Also, that filter has to be supported by whatever theme you're using... if it doesn't run the filter, your code will never be run

Comment: Paul - if I switch it to a add_action, it is called.  I am beginning to suspect the SEO plugins are stopping it.

Answer (score 1):

So depending on your theme, you'll need to take a different approach. By the sounds of it, you're using a theme that adds WordPress theme support for `title-tag` e.g. *twentynineteen*. In this case, your code would look like this:

```php
function add_dynamic_title( $aTitleParts ) {

    if ( isset( $aTitleParts[ 'title' ] ) && $aTitleParts[ 'title' ] == 'Details' ) {
        $aTitleParts[ 'title' ] = $_GET[ 'Name' ];
    }

    return $aTitleParts;
}

add_filter( 'document_title_parts', 'add_dynamic_title', 20 );
```

This filter uses an array where it contains, amongst other things, a key `title` and perhaps `tagline`. So in this case you set the array key value for `title` to whatever you'd like and return the whole array.

Comment: Brilliant, worked like a charm.  The share to facebook is still using the old name, so I will need to explore that.  But the tab is now what is passed by the Url param.

Comment: Fab, glad it worked for your page titles!  Feel free to mark the answer as accepted if it works, but if there's anything else extra needed to get this problem sorted, let me know...

Answer (score 1):

The following code gives you the ability to use `[facebook_title]` shortcode in the title and `[facebook_description]` respectively.

If you use any of *Yoast SEO*, *SEOPress* or *All in One SEO Pack* plugins, add these shortcodes primarily there.

Remove lines activating shortcodes in unused plugins.

```
// get your special title
function my_facebook_title() {
    return get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'post_meta_facebook_title', true );
}

// get your special description
function my_facebook_description() {
    return get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'post_meta_facebook_description', true );
}

// add hooks to shortcodes
add_shortcode( 'listing_title', 'my_facebook_title' );
add_shortcode( 'listing_description', 'my_facebook_description' );


// activate shortcode in the post headline
add_filter( 'the_title', 'do_shortcode' );

// activate shortcode for the single post <title>
add_filter( 'single_post_title', 'do_shortcode' );

//// Plugins (optional)

// activate shortcodes in SEOPress
add_filter( 'seopress_titles_title', 'do_shortcode' );
add_filter( 'seopress_titles_desc', 'do_shortcode' );


// activate shortcodes in Yoast SEO
add_filter( 'wpseo_title', 'do_shortcode' );
add_filter( 'wpseo_metadesc', 'do_shortcode' );


// activate shortcodes in All in One SEO Pack
add_filter( 'aioseop_title', 'do_shortcode' );
add_filter( 'aioseop_description', 'do_shortcode' );
```

**Update**: SEOPress and All in One SEO Pack support added.

Comment: sadly, I don't use Yoast. I use another SEO plugin-- bit easier for the client to manage than Yoast.   But I am going to look to see if there is a way to use these calls you reference.  Where is the documentation on it?

Comment: All-in-One-SEO also has filters. Which plugin do you use? There is no documentation in one block, it's all around.

Comment: SEOPress.  Easiest for non-technical owners who want to do it themselves and not pay for it.

Comment: SEOPress also has similar filters, so the routine is the same. The answer is updated.